# NSDateformatter does not format correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an NSDateformatter that is not working correctly. I got my date as a string like this.

```
2013-02-20 00:00:00
```

And I need to return it as an NSDate like this

```
2013-02-20
```

What I've got at the moment is this.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]
```

But this is not working.
Any help ?

Comment: You're setting the second format before the date is extracted from the string,  you're not storing the extracted date anywhere, and then you never convert the date back to a string.  (Note that an NSDate does not contain any format information in it.)

Comment: (Basically, you don't have the foggiest idea what you're doing, yet you have the temerity to blame it on NSDateFormatter.)

Comment: "foggiest idea…" — now thats is a phrase that I will assimilate for sure!

Comment: @HotLicks, That is an epic comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have more than on date to parse, it could be worthy to create one input and one output date formatter

```
static NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter;
static NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter;
if (!inputDateFormatter) {
    inputDateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
}
NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-20 00:00:00"];

NSString *string = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

result

```
2013-02-20
```

as NSDateFormatter are expensive to create, you should either store them in a singleton or declare them static to create them once for that method.

---

> And I need to return it as an NSDate like this

A date has no format, it is just a point in time. you will have to creta a string with the desired format where needed.

Comment: Leave the original comment: -1 because you should have used one single formatter and you're making things harder that they are.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, would you be so kind to explain, why it should be a single formatter?

Comment: In OOP if you need to use many times a variable you create a class instance variable. Now this is exactly what I would have done if I had to use this piece of code N times, and I wouldn't have used a static variable. Now this is irrelevant, since we should extend the discussion to the whole OP class, which isn't topic of the question.

Comment: A ivar doesn't guarantee it stays alive. And pleas, go ahead and vote more answers down.

Comment: I'm able to use ARC. So yes, it's guaranteed to stay alive unless I do some mess with the code.

Comment: Btw: did u ever realize apple uses static for re-use identifiers? They do it for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate* date=[dateFormat dateFromString: dateString];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate: date]);
```

This will work
try it

Comment: this wont be performant if this lines are supposed to executed more than once. NSDateFormatters are expensive. They should be re-used in some way.

Comment: All good objective-c practices are still valid. This is just an explanatory code snippet. Every user will decide what to do with this code, according to the needing.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri You mean every *decent* user.  I think most people will just copy and paste this...